# Threading is working perfectly on python2.7 but not on python3.4

Tags: python, multithreading

```
import threading
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, target, *args):
        self._des = target
        self._args = args
        threading.Thread.__init__(self,)
        self._stopper = threading.Event()    

    def run(self):
        self._des(*self._args)

    def stop(self):
        self._stopper.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stopper.isSet()
def add(a,b):
    print(a+b)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    f1 = MyThread(add,1,2)
    f1.start()
    f1.join()
```

The above code is working perfectly on python2.7 but when i tried it with 3.4 it shows the following error

```
TypeError: add() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'b'
```

Is there anyone who can help me to solve this.?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: shouldn't you be passing like `MyThread(target = add, args = (a, b))`

Comment: @warl0ck Nope. The `MyThread` constructor has `*args`.

Comment: yeah i noticed that author wants multiple/variable args dynamically, I have posted the modified working code snippet. Thanks @heemayl for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While assigning `self.args = args`, you get value as a tuple so you should be first taking/parsing it to tuple then pass it into your `add` function.
So all you have to do is make a tuple out of your `args`.

Below is the modified code with marked line changed.

```
import threading
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, target, *args):
        self._des = target
        self.args = tuple(args)  // making it to tuple
        threading.Thread.__init__(self,)
        self._stopper = threading.Event()    

    def run(self):
        self._des(*self.args)

    def stop(self):
        self._stopper.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stopper.isSet()
def add(a,b):
    print(a+b)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    f1 = MyThread(add, 1, 2)
    f1.start()
    f1.join()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

to keep it simple, this one works

```
def __init__(self, target, a,b):
    self._des = target
    self._a=a
    self._b=b  
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self._stopper = threading.Event()    

def run(self):
    self._des(self._a,self._b)
```

going by your way, you need to run the initialization first, because thats wiping out all values, like below

```
def __init__(self, target, *args):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self._des = target  
    self._args = tuple(args)        
    self._stopper = threading.Event()    

def run(self):
    self._des(self._args[0],self._args[1])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need a thread class which takes variable arguments .